# Calculating VDS in circuit

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis

I need to calculate the \$V_{DS2}\$ in the following circuit, but am unable to solve it. I know that \$I_{D1}=\frac{1}{2}k_n(V_{IN}-V_t)=0.4\$ mA and that with this value I can calculate \$V_{DS1}=V_{DD}-R_1 I_{D1}=1.5\$ V. But then I'm stuck, I think \$V_x = V_{DS1}\$ but \$V_{DD}\$ also connects there so it needs to drop voltage somewhere? Also I'm not sure what to do with the current source, since it's pointing downwards it is just an infinite resistance, but then the circuit isn't grounded?

[image: circuit]

Also note that \$\lambda=0\$.

Comment: Hint: \$V_{DS1}=V_{G2}\$, \$V_{G2}-V_{S2}=V_{GS2}\$, and \$I_{BIAS}=I_{D2}=f(V_{GS2})\$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted (devices in saturation),

$$ I_{D1}=\dfrac{1}{2}k_{n1}(V_{GS1}-V_T)^2$$
Same goes for \$I_{D2}\$.

$$ I_{D2}=\dfrac{1}{2}k_{n2}(V_{GS2}-V_T)^2$$

And \$V_{GS1}=V_{IN}\$. They also gave you \$I_{D2}=I_{BIAS}=1\text{mA}\$.

You could now use the equation for \$I_{D2}\$ and solve for \$V_{GS2}\$ (you have a value for everything else).

Keep in mind that \$V_{GS2}=V_X-V_{S2}\$. \$V_X\$ is easy to find since you have the current \$I_{D1}\$ and you have the value of \$R\$ too, it is indeed \$V_{DS1}\$.

So once you know \$V_{GS2}\$ from the \$I_{D2}\$ equation, you can solve for \$V_{S2}\$ (knowing \$V_X\$). And finally \$V_{DS2}\$ is just the difference between \$V_{D2}\$ and \$V_{S2}\$.